# Fill URL for CSS form testing

Tags: php, css, forms, printing, html-table

I wrote this simple form, but I don't know theory about filling form. In future I want filling my form from MySQL, but now I need somehow test my form:

```
<table>                             
    <tr>
        <td><p style="text-align: right">name:</p></td>                   
        <th><p style="text-align: left">',$name,'</p></th>                     
    </tr>                        
    <tr>
        <td><p style="text-align: right">age:</p></td>                   
        <th><p style="text-align: left">',$age,'</p></th>                     
    </tr>                       
    <tr>   
        <td><p style="text-align: right">place:</p></td>                   
        <th><p style="text-align: left">',$place,'</p></th>                     
    </tr>                                                                        
</table>
```

So, I need replace `$name, $age, $place` in url like: `http://test.mydomain.com/testform.php?name="Name Example"`... How can I write/get url in correct form for result name: Name Example, not `name: ',$name,'`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to send a form with [`GET`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.2) method.

You must use the `method="GET"` in your **HTML** `<form>` tag.

**Example of your form.php:**

```
<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="testform.php">
    <!-- your form goes here -->
</FORM>
```

Now, if you want to get the variables in your testform.php page, you need to use `$_GET` in **PHP**.

**Example of your testform.php:**

```
<?php

    // get FORM variables
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $age  = $_GET['age'];

   // print variables
   echo $name;
   echo '<br>';
   echo $age;
?>
```

To print the variable in a table like your example, you can retrieve first the variables, and then put into the table:

**Another example:**

```
<?php

    // get FORM variables
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    // ... 
?>
<table>                             
    <tr>
        <td><p style="text-align: right">name:</p></td>                   
        <th><p style="text-align: left"><?php echo $name ?></p></th>                     
    </tr>     
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to make something like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

You can check out the w3schools page about php form handling here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Everything is explained over here. (If I understand you right). 
Is this what you are looking for?